# Overlapping 1 px Borders making a thicker border

Tags: html, css, border, jquery-masonry

Is there a way, when I have over lapping (touching) div's, to make the 1px border not become 2 pixels. And I know I could just put a border on 2 of the sides, but then the one edge of the div wouldn't have a border. By the way, I'm using jQuery Masonry.

Comment: if you are using masonry ... you are probably designing responsively /  so make sure to look into :nth-of-type ---  check out these  http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/     http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/

Comment: Where's your code? Where can we see what you've tried? Overlapping or touching? What is "the 1px border"?

Answer (score 8):

yes the div on the right would look something like this

```
     border: 1px solid #fff;
     border-left: none;
```

the second border-left will override the left border that was just put on there

EDIT:

ok, since youre using jQuery masonary - do it like this

```
            .container {
              width:50px;
              height:80px;
              border:1px solid black;
              margin-right: -1px;
              margin-bottom: -1px;
              }
```

the overlapping method I mentioned will work

Comment: That works, but the left border on say a div without one next to it is nonexistent. [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mnk27pth7fi4cwj/Screen%20Shot%202012-08-26%20at%208.26.06%20PM.png)

Comment: they are going to need different classes , like "box" (with no right border) then another class called "last" , so when it is at the end , and you need a right border , then class="box last"

Comment: If you've heard of jQuery Masonry (I haven't before today), it uses divs, not li's, so that wouldn't work either. And it places the divs in a semi-random manner, so it would require JS, I believe.

Comment: Technically you could absolute position them and actually put it 1px on top of the other div - but the way i mentioned is really best practice

Comment: you could add margin: 5px;  if you'd like a little space between them , and li's and div's use classes in exactly the same manner

Comment: do you have a link ? I could look at it and change the css for you

Comment: the border-top: -1px in .container .post fixes the double border on the top's of the div's , I'm trying to figure out why the side borders are still double

Answer (score 2):

Combining borders and margins (even with border-box) is tricky because your layout depends on the container width. It is better to add a child to the element positioned by Masonry and style that...

```
.container .post {
   float: left;
   width: 240px;
}

.container .text {
    outline: 1px solid #999;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
```

`outline` allows the border to appear "outside" the div which makes them easier to overlap

http://jsfiddle.net/4xmUY/

(if you happen to use this answer please accept Scott's answer as this should be a comment on his answer but the explanation doesn't fit there).

Comment: That works almost perfectly. The layout only has 3 columns instead of 4, though.

Comment: You can either bump up your container width to ~964px or use my updated answer (add a child element). The more robust solution is my updated answer.